# How to install older version of python when we have installed a newer version

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, dlib

I'm a novice python programmer and I have installed python 3.7 and 2.7. I tried to install python 3.5.7 with 'python setup.py install' command in cmd(for use dlib library) but it didn't install and this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "setup.py", line 25, in <module>sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CFLAGS'] = cflags + ' ' + py_cflags_nodist
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

I tried to install python 3.4.9 but same error occured.

Comment: are you on windows

Comment: Yes, I use windows 7

Comment: make a new environment ,each containing different versions of python

Comment: just install using the installer and set your path

Comment: in pycharm , you can set your interpreter in settings in runtime, just install both in different locations and remember the location of python.exe

Comment: my advice is use google colaboratory for online python for different versions to try.

Comment: Do do not use python >=3.0 and <= 3.6! If a python file can be run by python3.4.9, it also can be run by python3.7. So there is **no need** to install another version of python3!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popular Linux distros, like Ubuntu, come with both python2 and python3. You can set one as default python and access other as python3 (or python2).

On Windows, the executable is just `python` (NOT `python2`). The newer python will overwrite the older executable (not the actual installation files, but the environment path).

**Way 1:**
Instead of running `python filename.py`, give path to python binary. Like `C:/python27/bin/python filename.py`, make sure the path to python is correct. This will use python from particular directory.
This can be cumbersome, I don't recommend this.

**Way 2:**
Make an alias python2 referring to /path/to/python2, run as `python2 filename.py`. Don't forget to add this alias to environment variables.

**Way 3:**
Set up a virtual environment.
The default `venv` [now] included in python3, does not support creating virtual environment with a different python version. Use `virtualenv` instead.

```
virtualenv --python=C:/python27/bin/python2.7 /path/to/new/virtualenv/
/path/to/new/virtualenv/Scripts/activate.bat
```

Virtualenv documentation: https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/

Answer (score 0):

You can always install another version of python side by side.

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/

See this link for downloading your desired python version executable or source code.

on windows you need to for `.exe` or `.msi` file
on Linux you need to for `.tgz` file (we need to compile to install)
on MacOS you need to for `.pkg` file